# bootstrap grid elements not inline in small devices

Tags: html, css

I have a problem. Now I have bunch of divs in my code and i am using bootstrap, what I want is to make my content with control buttons be inline in small devices (like phone).However, i get something like this:

[image: fail]

but that button should be in same line. Here is my code:

```
<div class='container-fluid info text-center'>
    <h1>Truputėlis apie mane</h1>
    <div class='row'>
        <div class='col-xs-1 col-sm-1 col-md-4'>
            <a href='#'><div class='controls left'><span class='glyphicon glyphicon-triangle-left' class='controls'></span>
            </div></a>
        </div>
        <div class='col-xs-10 col-sm-10 col-md-4 about_me'>
            <div style='background: url(notebook8.png);font-family: Dynalight; font-size:28px;padding-top:15px;padding-left:50px;padding-bottom:5px;margin:0 auto;border:1px solid grey;'>
                    <img src='http://www.arlongpark.net/customavatars/avatar23489_6.gif' style='width:80px; height:80px; background-color:white; border:1px solid black; border-radius:150px;'><br/>
                 <div class='about_me_text text-left'>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class='col-xs-1 col-sm-1 col-md-4'></div>
            <a href='#' >
                <div class='controls right'>
                    <span class='glyphicon glyphicon-triangle-right'></span>
                </div>
            </a>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

What should I do? Sorry for my terrible english, hope you understood something...

Comment: Can you exactly point out the issue on the [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/wand0twf/) I've created?

Comment: I want that in small screen that two buttons were in same place as in big screen (inline with that content with photo) but right button is in other line as you see in my image

Comment: use css media queries

Comment: what do you actually mean? how should i use media here?